# I am having trouble adding timer to my code

Tags: python, timer

I am working on this project with a motion sensor in which I would like to have the monitor turned off when there is no motion after a certain amount of time has passed. But every time there is a motion I would like the timer to reset.

I have the code working for turning the monitor on and off with motion, but how do I add the timer?

Any help will be appreciated. My code:

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
import time
from subprocess import call

pir = MotionSensor(4)


while True:
 pir.wait_for_motion()
 print("Screen On")
 call(["/usr/bin/vcgencmd", "display_power", "1"])
 time.sleep(30)

 pir.wait_for_no_motion()
 print("Screen Off")
 call(["/usr/bin/vcgencmd", "display_power", "0"])
 time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as `wait_for_motion()`, gpiozero also provides a variable, `motion_detected`. The code below sets a variable, `startpoint` to the current time in seconds since 1/1/1970. It then starts a loop which:

- Checks if motion is detected - if so, sets the `startpoint` variable back to the current time (which, of course, will be different to what it was previously) and turns on the display.
- Checks if the `startpoint` variable is more than 30 seconds before the current time. Because every motion detection resets this variable, we know that there must have been at least 30 seconds since the last motion detection. If so, turns off the display.

  `startpoint = time.time()
  while True:
      if pir.motion_detected:
          startpoint = time.time() 
          call(["/usr/bin/vcgencmd", "display_power", "1"]) 
          print("Display on")
      elif time.time() > (startpoint+30): 
          call(["/usr/bin/vcgencmd", "display_power", "0"]) 
          print("Display off")`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `threading` for this.

```py
from enum import Enum
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from subprocess import call
from threading import Timer
from time import sleep
from typing import Optional

pir = MotionSensor(4)
timer: Optional[Timer] = None

class MonitorState(Enum):
    ON = "1"
    OFF = "0"

def set_monitor_state(state: str):
    call(["/usr/bin/vcgencmd", "display_power", state.value])

def start_timer():
    global timer
    if timer:
        timer.cancel()
    timer = Timer(30, set_monitor_state, (MonitorState.OFF,))
    timer.start()


start_timer()

while True:
    pir.wait_for_motion()
    start_timer()
    set_monitor_state(MonitorState.ON)
```

I'm not sure if the `Timer` actually counts as being `done` when the callback returns or before that. In the first case you could run into troubles when the `set_monitor_state(MonitorState.ON)` get called while the timer runs it's callback on another thread. You might want to use locking in this case.